# Number of edges of planer graph

Tags: graph-theory

A convex polyhedron has 20 vertices and 12 faces.  Each face of the polyhedron is bounded by the same number of edges.  What is this common number?

Comment: Do you know this equality? $V-E+F=2$ So you can have the number of edges. Then you can see that $Fx=2E$ where $x$ is what you are looking. why?

Comment: I know the equation for connected planer graph.  But after that, I am stuck.  Could you explain why Fx = 2E is correct?

Comment: ok, i posted as an answer.

Comment: I understand! Thank you for your post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be the number of edges that bound each face in the polyhedron, then if we go face by face we will get $Fx$ edges, but each edge is shared with $2$ faces, hence we have counted twice each edge, then $Fx=2E.$ This combined with Euler characteristic equation gives us $x=\frac{2E}{F}=\frac{2(V+F-2)}{F}.$